# Openbravo invalid source path error when installing new modules/updating

Tags: openbravo

I´m a beginner using OpenBravo ERP.

I installed the software on a Feroda machine using the custom installation guide.

All went fine and the system started up. I then entered on tha default Openbravo account, choose System Administrator role, went to Application->General Setup->Application->Module Management to install some local packages for Brazil. I saw "21 updates available". Either trying to update the packages, or to install my local packages I´m getting the same error when I click "Install":

ERROR: org.openbravo.base.exception.OBException: invalid source path

Can someone help me to solve that ?

Thanks!

Comment: goto the modules folder (opt/openbravoerp/modules) and check all the installed modules are available there.. If so do "ant update.database smartbuild"  , this command should be successful inorder to see your new module's feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a permission issue. Can you check if the tomcat user(or the user which writes to the tomcat directory) has permissions to write to the webapps directory.